How to get back to the same player level?
Me and two friends play offline co-op on Minecraft Dungeons and at some point I did the Staff Only (Secret) achievement. I didn't realise I got XP and then I realised this when I levelled up slightly before them.
How do I make it so we all have the same level again?

Levels are not important in Minecraft Dungeons, only your equipment total power counts when selecting the next dungeon's difficulty.
Actually, player's levels are just a "currency", because with every level-up you obtain Enchantment Points that you can spend in Ancient Hunts. There's no downside in playing with a friend that is one level below.
By the way, if this bothers you, your friend can simply play a random dungeon with a low dfficulty, and gain some exp to reach your level.

No that's not what I mean they're the same level as me but e difference is just the xp that you get from the Staff Only achievement, and the ancient hunts use Enchantement points not levels but you do get them from lvling up

@PianoCat98 I fixed the answer, it was pretty much correct btw. I don't get your problem, what's the matter with the different exp earned? Probably the player hosting the game got a bit more than your friends.

so im thinking of a sloution like this:
we play a short mission, when i level up we go back to camp and then just they lvl up and them when they do they go back to camp and im player 1 again
would that work or does going back to camp get rid of the xp?

@PianoCat98 leaving a mission from the menu lets you keep gears, emeralds and exp
